# Guzzle 6 API Call with an Array

Tags: php, api, guzzle

I am wanting to perform and API call that has an array using Guzzle.

In my diagnostics I have an issue with Guzzle escaping the array characters `[`and `]` the url should look like this.

`https://url-to-app.app/api/v1/resource?api_key=123456789&user_id=123&status[]=New&status[]=In%20Progress`

but the URL is coming out like so

`https://url-to-app.app/api/v1/resource?api_key=123456789&user_id=123&status%5B1%5D=New&status%5B1%5D=In%20Progress`

I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong or if there is a workaround (Maybe this is a feature?) but here is my code.

```
$not_complete = [
    'New',
    'In Progress',
    'Waiting for Parts',
    'Waiting on Customer',
    'Scheduled',
    'Customer Reply',
    'Parts to be Ordered',
    'To be Delivered',
    'To be Contacted'
];

$user_id = 123;
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://url-to-app.app/api/v1/resource', [
    'query' => [
        'api_key' => '123456789',
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'status'  => $not_complete
    ]
]);
$tickets = json_decode($res->getBody());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that this is untested

you shouldn't need to specify the square brackets in the key of the query array.  If you do this Guzzle will automatically assume that its plain text and has to be escaped.

```
'query' => [
    'api_key' => '123456789',
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'status'  => $not_complete // providing this is an array it should work
]
```

try the above and let Guzzle do the formatting for you.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong code in question. But both methods yield the same result. i.e. Characters are escaped.